Preview locales
How do I quickly preview what a locale looks like? E.g: is there something like
$ localepreview en_DK.UTF-8

Of course, I immediately think of a script like
#!/bin/bash
LOCALE=$1

export LANG=$LOCALE
export LC_TIME=$LOCALE
export LC_NUMERIC=$LOCALE
export LC_MONETARY=$LOCALE

echo "Date and Time (locale: $LOCALE):"
date
echo

echo "Numeric Formatting:"
printf "Number: %'.2f\n" 1234567.89

But what about the other variables? Is there a convenient file there in the
system that give such examples? Something like
$ less /usr/share/iso-codes/json/iso_3166-1.json


If you're OK with using a web service, there's https://icu4c-demos.unicode.org/icu-bin/locexp

You could do something like:
LC_ALL=en_DK.UTF-8 locale -kc $(
  locale | sed '/^LC_/!d;/^LC_ALL=/d;s/=.*//'
)

(assuming $IFS not modified from its default) which would give you keyword=values for each locale category.
That will not give you all the information stored there as some of them would be very hard to render usefully. For instance, that will not give you the list of collating elements and how they sort between each other, not all the characters in the charset, or how bytes and decoded/encoded to/from characters (which often is done by some binary software components) but you could look at the source files that were used to generate the locale if known where you'll find most of the information.
For instance, on a GNU system, the en_DK.UTF-8 locale will usually have been generated from the /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_DK and /usr/share/i18n/charmaps/UTF-8.gz files which are plain text files (compressed with gzip for the charmap one here). Those in turn may include other files which will also be found in the same directory.

Thanks. That's helpful. LC_ALL=$(locale -a | fzf) can also be set for more interactivity.

You can run the following code.  Add printf's for any value you want to display.
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# check all locales you currently have generated on your machine
# and display the numeric separator character
locale -a | 
  while read -r l; do 
    printf '%s: %s\n' "$l" "$(LC_NUMERIC=$l locale -k thousands_sep)"
done

Found where I got this from:
StackExchange
